# Pyside and Cython

Tags: visual-studio-2012, python-2.7, pyside, cython

I have written a GUI by using pyside but I am facing problems when I use Cython and Visual Studio to compile an application. This application (exe) crashes every time and there are no indicators what causes it.

But If I use pyexe to make an application, everything goes well and this application works. What are the problem/problems with the Cython and visual studio?

example code

```
import sys

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.line_edit = QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)

        self.output = QTextEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.output)

        font = self.output.font()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Console")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setStyleHint(font.Monospace)
        font.setStyleStrategy(font.PreferAntialias)
        self.output.setCurrentFont(font)

        self.line_edit.returnPressed.connect(self.line_edit_text_changed)

        self.output.append("{:<16.4}{:<16.6}".format(10.23, 1235.77265))
        self.output.append("{:<16.4}{:<16.6}".format(10.23, 12.345))
        self.show()

    def line_edit_text_changed(self):
        self.output.append(self.line_edit.text())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mw = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: I'm currently having an issue where the connect for a Python signal appears to be generating a segmentation fault.

Comment: seems like Pyside/Cython have a bug?... I have tried compiling my app with cython but some functionalities of PySide were not working..see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965776/pyside-addtojavascriptwindowobject-not-working-properly-when-application-is-com

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so here's what I did:

I took lines like

```
signal.connect( self.function )
```

and turned them into

```
connector = lambda : self.function
signal.connect( connector )
```

Near as I can tell, the problem is with how Cython converts the functions to C that is callable from Python.  It doesn't quite work with the hack that Signal connect uses to manage calls between Python and C.  So, what I'm doing is creating a Python function object (the lambda function) and using that as the Python object.

Calling the Cython function is happy because you're calling it using typical Python syntax.  Connecting the signal is happy because it has a normal Python function.

I tested this using your example and changing using the following lines worked:

```
con = lambda : self.line_edit_text_changed()
self.line_edit.returnPressed.connect( con )
```

EDIT: To make my life simpler, I also created a function to handle some of this for me

```
def connect_signal( signal, function ):
    def intermediary( *args, **kwargs ):
        function( *args, **kwargs )
    signal.connect( intermediary )
```

This can just be placed in some common file and used in place of the usual syntax.  It works for Cythonized and non-Cythonized files.

Comment: Months later, I've determined a pretty significant drawback to this method; namely that the connected functions don't get deconstructed properly.  Because intermediary is its own object, it does not get deconstructed when function is deconstructed.  This can lead to various problems when an object whose function was connected is destroyed.  I have migrated my project away from Cython, so I haven't figured out a way to resolve this particular issue.