# Pyside: addToJavaScriptWindowObject not working properly when application is compiled with cython

Tags: python, pyside, cython, qtwebkit

I have built an application that runs a couple thousand of lines of code.

I am trying to hide the codes by compiling the python codes to c codes and then to an object file.

This application works well in pyside. I converted this python file .`py` to a `.c` file and compiled the c to and object file `.o`. The name of this file is `test2.py`  and my steps to convert it to an `.o` file:

```
 cython --embed -o test2.c test2.py
```

from the above I now compile the test2.c to test2.o as follows

```
gcc -I /usr/include/python2.7 -o test2.o -fPIC test2.c -lpython2.7 -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl
```

**My problem is the minimize and close button designed in the webkit frame  is not working after compiling (However It works well when executed from python file) and other addtoJavascripWindowObjects are not working**

I developed a simple frame window model with nothing inside using Pyside

The test2.py file codes are as follows:
My codes are below

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import json
import threading
from time import sleep
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import QWebView, QWebSettings
from PySide.QtNetwork import QNetworkRequest

title_bar_str="""<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

<section id="exit_panel">
    <div id="window_title_meta_container">
        <img id="window_title_icon" draggable="false">
        <div id="window_title"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="min_close_container">
    <div id="min_ap" class="win_signals">_</div>
    <div id="close_ap" class="win_signals">x</div>
    </div>
</section>
<style>
img#window_title_icon{
    display: none;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    vertical-align:top;
    border:none;
}
#window_title_meta_container{
    float:left;
    color:grey !important;
}
#window_title_meta_container,#window_title_icon,#window_title{
    display:inline-block;
}
#title_bar{
    color:black;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(blue,grey);
    font-size:15px;
}
.btns{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    border:solid red 1px;
    background:red;
    left:85%
}
body{
    border:solid black 1px;
    height:100%;
    margin:auto;
    background:red;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;

}
body:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
html,body{
    overflow:hidden
}
.win_signals{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;

}
#close_ap,#min_ap{
color: white;
background: rgb(18, 110, 201) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
border-radius: 10px;            
}
#close_ap:hover,#min_ap:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    background:green;
}
#min_close_container{
position: relative;;
display: inline-block;
}

#exit_panel{
    text-align: right;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#104477, #000) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    color: white;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById('close_ap').onclick=function(){
        console.log(trigger_title_signals.close(''))
    }
    document.getElementById('min_ap').onclick=function(){
        console.log(trigger_title_signals.minimize(''))
    }    


}

</script>
</body>
</html>
</doctype>

"""
class Frame(QFrame,QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Frame,self).__init__()
        self.gui_height=None
        self.title_bar_height=None
        self.html_title_bar_webview=web_view_with_move(self)
        self.html_title_bar_webview.init_signals()
        self.html_title_bar_webview.setContent(title_bar_str)
        self.html_title_bar_webview.page().mainFrame().setScrollBarPolicy(Qt.Vertical,Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.html_title_bar_webview.page().mainFrame().setScrollBarPolicy(Qt.Horizontal,Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.html_title_bar_webview.page().mainFrame().addToJavaScriptWindowObject("Frame",self)      
        self.title_bar_q_widget=title_bar_q()
        self.title_bar_q_widget.setMaximumHeight(35)
        self.title_bar_q_widget.setMinimumHeight(35)
        self.title_bar_q_widget.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        #self.title_bar_q_widget.layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.title_bar_q_widget_layout=QGridLayout()
        self.title_bar_q_widget_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.title_bar_q_widget_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.title_bar_q_widget_layout.setVerticalSpacing(0);
        self.title_bar_q_widget_layout.addWidget(self.html_title_bar_webview)
        self.title_bar_q_widget.setLayout(self.title_bar_q_widget_layout)
        #self.html_title_bar_webview.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript("Frame.adjustTitleBarHeight(getComputedStyle(document.body,null).height)")  
        #######
        self.adstar_gui_webview=web_view()
        self.adstar_gui_webview.page().mainFrame().addToJavaScriptWindowObject("Frame",self)          
        self.adstar_gui_webview.show()

        self.adstar_gui_webview.page().mainFrame().setScrollBarPolicy(Qt.Vertical,Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.adstar_gui_q_widget=QWidget()
        self.adstar_gui_q_widget.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.adstar_gui_q_widget_layout=QGridLayout()
        self.adstar_gui_q_widget_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.adstar_gui_q_widget_layout.setVerticalSpacing(0)
        self.adstar_gui_q_widget_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.adstar_gui_q_widget_layout.addWidget(self.adstar_gui_webview)
        self.adstar_gui_q_widget.setLayout(self.adstar_gui_q_widget_layout)

        ######
        #self.html_title_bar.show()
#        self.adstar_gui.show()
        self.layout=QGridLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.layout.setVerticalSpacing(0)
        #self.layout.setHorizontalSpacing(0)        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.title_bar_q_widget)   
        self.layout.addWidget(self.adstar_gui_q_widget)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    @Slot(str)
    def python_evaluate_variable(self,var):
        global stop_session
        if var != "":
            exec(var)                    
    @Slot(str)
    def setWindowTitle(self,win_title_str):
        self.win_title_str=win_title_str
        self.html_title_bar_webview.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('window_title').textContent='%s'" % (self.win_title_str,))

    def closeEvent(self,event):
        global main
        #super(Frame,self).closeEvent(event)
        try:
            if main==None:
                return
        except NameError:
            main=None
        if self==main:
            for child_win in all_windows:
                child_win.close()
                #del self
                QCoreApplication.processEvents()

class web_view_with_move(QWebView):
    def __init__(self,qframe):
        super(web_view_with_move,self).__init__()
        self.mouseup=None
        self.mousedown=None
        self.qframe=qframe
        self.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.WebAttribute.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
        super(web_view_with_move,self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)        
        self.mouseup=True
        self.mousedown=False

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(web_view_with_move,self).mousePressEvent(event)        
        self.offset = event.pos()
        self.mouseup=False
        self.mousedown=True

    def init_signals(self):
        self.title_bar_signals=title_bar_signals(self.qframe)
        self.page().mainFrame().addToJavaScriptWindowObject("trigger_title_signals",self.title_bar_signals)



    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(web_view_with_move,self).mouseMoveEvent(event)         
        if self.mousedown is True:
            x=event.globalX()
            y=event.globalY()
            x_w = self.offset.x()
            y_w = self.offset.y()
            self.qframe.move(x-x_w, y-y_w)


class title_bar_signals(QObject):
    def __init__(self,qframe):
        super(title_bar_signals,self).__init__()
        self.qframe=qframe
    @Slot(str)
    def close(self,tmp):
        self.qframe.close()
        #del self
        QCoreApplication.processEvents()
    @Slot(str)
    def minimize(self,tmp):
        self.qframe.showMinimized()
        #self.qframe.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMinimized)
        QCoreApplication.processEvents()

class title_bar_q(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(title_bar_q,self).__init__()


    def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
        super(title_bar_q,self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self.mouseup=True
        self.mousedown=False



    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(title_bar_q,self).mousePressEvent(event)        
        self.offset = event.pos()
        self.mouseup=False
        self.mousedown=True


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(title_bar_q,self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        if self.mousedown is True:
            x=event.globalX()
            y=event.globalY()
            x_w = self.offset.x()
            y_w = self.offset.y()
            main.move(x-x_w, y-y_w)

class web_view(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(web_view,self).__init__()
        self.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.WebAttribute.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)

def main():
    try:
        Qapp=QApplication(sys.argv)
        ev_runner=QCoreApplication
        main=Frame()
        main.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        main.adstar_gui_q_widget.setMinimumWidth(850)
        main.adstar_gui_q_widget.setMaximumWidth(850)    
        main.setMinimumHeight(790)
        main.setMaximumHeight(790)
        main.setWindowTitle("Application")
        ev=QCoreApplication
        main.show()
        QCoreApplication.processEvents()
        Qapp.exec_()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass    
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

#### Note: How I implemented the title bar

I created a webview frame in the class named `Frame`

```
self.html_title_bar_webview=web_view_with_move(self)
```

I executed a class init_signal() which adds the javascript window object

```
self.html_title_bar_webview.init_signals()
```

[image]

Comment: I doubt if either of these really solve the problem but: 1) `QFrame` inherits from `QObject` so what do you get from using multiple inheritance? 2) If the code you're trying to hide is the html/css it will be trivial to extract that from the object file (the python code will be harder though).

Comment: This just looks like a bug in PySide. The same code works fine when using PyQt4 with cython.

Comment: @ekhumoro glad to know this works well in PyQT as compared to PySide